# General term formula for combination of arithmetic and geometric progressions

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

Let $a_n;\;n> 1$ be a sequence of positive numbers such that $a_1, a_2, a_3$ are in $AP$, $a_2, a_3, a_4$ are in $GP$, $a_3, a_4, a_5$ are in $AP$, $a_4, a_5, a_6$ are in $GP$, and so on. Find an expression for $a_n$ in terms of $a_1$ and $a_2$.

I did 
$a_3=2a_2+a_1$
$a_4=a_2+a_1\bigg(\frac{1}{a_2}-4\bigg)$
$a_5=6a_2+a_1\bigg(\frac{2}{a_2}-7\bigg)$
But I can't see how to write $a_n$ in terms of $a_1$ and $a_2$... Can somenone help me? Thanks for attention!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Apply induction to prove:
$$
a_n=\frac1{a_2}\times\begin{cases}
\left(\frac{n+1}2a_2-\frac{n-1}2a_1\right)\left(\frac{n-1}2a_2-\frac{n-3}2a_1\right),& n\text{ odd},\\
\left(\frac{n}2a_2-\frac{n-2}2a_1\right)^2,& n\text{ even}.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Very good! But, you know how to do this question without induction?

Comment: Nice job. Let me add, that a couple of conditions needs to be written up for cases that are not true with the above formula: I immediately thought seeing this that if all elements are equal, they satisfy the conditions. But if I plug $a_2 = a_1$ in the above, I get $a_1$ for odd, but $-a_1$ for even. And there might be other solutions like this (or not, I cannot prove...), hence the conditions I mention.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó I don't quite understand how $\frac{a^2}a=-a$ for even $n$. The only condition I see $a_2\ne0$.

Comment: Well, you have changed the formula since then, the coefficients were the other way round.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó I just have changed the sign inside the brackets for beauty reasons. $(-1)^2=1$ still... :)

Comment: Ah, my bad, I missed the squaring.

Comment: @Tas Why don't you like the induction?